# React Native error "Native module cannot be null"

Tags: ios, react-native

My React Native project was working perfectly fine, and now suddenly won't run on iOS, saying `Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.`.

I get no stack trace, no problematic package, nothing:

[image]

I understand that's not a reproducible example, but how can I find *what* exactly it's having an issue with? I've seen elsewhere people having a stack trace to follow, but I have no context or any other information.

I've tried:

- deleting node_modules and Pods/Podfile.lock
- cleaning the build folder
- running `react-native link` manually

How can I begin debugging this, seeing I'm getting no other context at all?

Comment: Have you run `npx pod-install`?

Comment: Yeah I've done so a lot, deleted Pods/Podfile and tried again - same with node_modules. I guess I'm just desperate to find out _which_ module is missing, as I can't find this information anywhere.